# nullmailer send success messages to mail.err?

Tags: email, debian

i've installed nullmailer vi aptitude on debian squeeze. When i checked the log files I noticed that even success messages are logged in mail.err..

Any ideas why and how to turn it off?

Regards

=========

cat /var/log/mail.err

```
Feb 27 17:12:07 localhost nullmailer[3528]: smtp: Succeeded: 250 2.0.0 4f4bab56-00012f6e   Message accepted for delivery
Feb 27 17:13:06 localhost nullmailer[3583]: smtp: Succeeded: 250 2.0.0 4f4bab92-00012f70      Message accepted for delivery
Feb 27 17:14:07 localhost nullmailer[3607]: smtp: Succeeded: 250 2.0.0 4f4babcf-00012f71 Message accepted for delivery
```

default syslog-config:

```
...    
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log

#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess its a bug

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=632015

Have a fix for it